# Difference between Bmx280 and Bmx280SensorDriver classes in Android Things bmx280 driver?

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-things

I'm writing an app using Android Things and want to use the [`bmx280` driver](https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/tree/master/bmx280) to read environmental values (temperature, barometric pressure, etc). There appear to be two different drivers: `Bmx280` and  `Bmx280SensorDriver`. Which one should I be using to read temperature values/pressure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Bmx280` lets you interact directly with the sensor peripheral so you can manually read temperature samples from it:

```
private Bmx280 bmx280;

try {
    bmx280 = new Bmx280(i2cBusName);
    bmx280.setTemperatureOversampling(Bmx280.OVERSAMPLING_1X);
    float temperature = bmx280.readTemperature();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle errors
}

// remember to close bmx280 later
```

`Bmx280SensorDriver` is meant to be registered with the system. In this case you do not interact with the hardware directly, instead you use the standard Android [`SensorManager` APIs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html) to listen for temperature readings:

```
private Bmx280SensorDriver sensorDriver;
private SensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

try {
    sensorDriver = new Bmx280SensorDriver(BoardDefaults.getI2cBus());
    sensorManager.registerDynamicSensorCallback(mDynamicSensorCallback);
    sensorDriver.registerTemperatureSensor();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle errors
}

private SensorManager.DynamicSensorCallback mDynamicSensorCallback
        = new SensorManager.DynamicSensorCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onDynamicSensorConnected(Sensor sensor) {
        if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE) {
            // Our sensor is connected. Start receiving temperature data.
            sensorManager.registerListener(mTemperatureListener, sensor,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }
    }

    /* other callbacks omitted */
};

// remember to unregister and close sensorDriver later
```

The benefit of the latter approach is that the device might have other ways to generate sensor readings, so you don't have to rely on just the `Bmx280` in case something else provides better readings, or the `Bmx280` stops working, etc. (You can think of this like Android's fused location provider; location data can be determined by different providers under different conditions, and the system tries to report the best information at any given time.) Also, the system takes care of things like polling the sensor data, so you don't have to create your own logic for that.

TL;DR -- If you want to manually read sensor data on demand, you can use `Bmx280` directly. If you want regular polling of sensor readings and don't care what's generating the data, use `Bmx280SensorDriver` and the `SensorManager` APIs.